# How do I get each python import on a different line when using Alt+Enter to magically import in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Currently if i do Alt+Enter on a function in a different module which isn't imported yet it simply adds it to a an existing import line.

Say I have:

```
from my_package.my_module import do_something

my_module.do_something()
```

Then I type:

```
from my_package.my_module import do_something

do_something()
do_something_else()  # My new line
```

I love that I can simply Alt+Enter on `do_something_else` and it gets imported. But what happens is this:

```
from my_package.my_module import do_something, do_something_else

do_something()
do_something_else()
```

While what I would like to happen is this:

```
from my_package.my_module import do_something
from my_package.my_module import do_something_else

do_something()
do_something_else()
```

I looked into the settings, but none of the ones I saw seemed right.

These are the ones I've looked at for now:

[image: Editor > Code Style > Python]

[image: Editor > General > Code Folding]

[image: Editor > General > Auto Import]

Where else can I look? Seems like something which should be possible. Maybe one of the options above is the one I'm looking for, but just didn't understand was the right one?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there isn't a setting to automate what you want. It's also not clear why you want it; the current arrangement makes it more obvious they're coming from the same place.

Comment: Mainly because of line length, and not wanting to split import lines using `\\`. Removing and adding modules also become more obvious in git, making it easier to compare what actual changes have been done.

Comment: Please not that I've changed the above example. I forgot my case was importing functions, not modules. Probably the same issue, but I want the problem to reflect what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @jonsharpe There are some instances where you would want them explicitly in a new line. e.g if you do git blame you can see which commit introduces that dependency.

Comment: I use [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) for formatting. You can [integrate black with PyCharm](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can now be done easily:

```
Settings > Code Style > Python > Imports
```

Then under `Structure of "from" imports` check the `Always split imports` option.

[image: Image of import settings]

Answer (score 1):

Currently there does not seem to be a way to do this, but there is an open ticket that you can up vote if you would like to have this feature.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20100

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible now in Pycharm 2018.3 according to [this comment here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20100#focus=streamItem-27-3113709-0-0)